# angular2 RC1 Some Routers have no Provider

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

After upgrading to RC1 from beta, I am having some issues with routing.  Some of the Routes work fine while others give me the following exception:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
```

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet],
  providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    StudentService,
    ReportService,
    UserService,
    ClassService,
    PropertiesService
 ]
})

@Routes([
{ // child route
    path: '/admin/...',
    name: 'Admin',
    component: AdministratorComponent
},
{ path: '*', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '/filter', name: 'Filter', component: FilterComponent },
{ path: '/profile',      name: 'Profile',  component: ProfileComponent  },
{ path: '/credits', name: 'Credits', component: ReportComponent},
{ path: '/approve', name: 'Approve', component: ApproveComponent},
{ path: '/filter-class', name: 'FilterClass', component: FilterClassComponent},
{ path: '/class', name: 'Class', component: ClassComponent}

])
```

Here is the administrator.component.ts which has the child routing

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-administrator',
templateUrl: 'app/components/administrator/administrator.component.html',
//styleUrls: ['app/administrator.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
directives: [RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers: []

})

@Routes([
{path: '/profile/:id', name: 'Profile', component: ProfileComponent},
{path: '/approve/:id', name: 'Approve', component: ApproveComponent},
{path: '/filter', name: 'Filter', component: FilterComponent},
{path: '/filter-class', name: 'FilterClass', component:    FilterClassComponent},
{path: '/class/:id', name: 'Class', component: ClassComponent},
])
```

I've included the html below:

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>
```

routing works^

```
<a class="list-group-item" *ngIf="user.isAdmin" [class.active]="getLinkStyle('/admin/')" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['Admin', 'Filter']">Student Management<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

routing doesn't work ^

```
<a class="list-group-item" *ngIf="!user.isAdmin" [class.active]="getLinkStyle('/profile')" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['Profile',{id: userConst.user.studentId}]">My Profile</a>
```

routing works ^

```
<a class="list-group-item" *ngIf="!user.isAdmin" [class.active]="getLinkStyle('/credits')" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['Credits']">My Credits</a>
```

routing works ^

```
<a class="list-group-item" *ngIf="user.isAdmin" [class.active]="getLinkStyle('/filter-class')" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['FilterClass']">Class Management</a>
```

routing doesn't work ^

Comment: It is relevant in which component the `[routerLink]` are. This is not obvious from the code in your question.

Comment: The routerLink is matched with the @Routes based on Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- don't add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` on each component, only once at the root component.
- `/...` in path: `'/admin/...'`, for child routes didn't work for me in rc.x. Try removing `/...`
- routes in the new router don't have a `name`. Only `path` and `component` (others are planned)
- with the new router the `[routerLink]`s take a list of path segments, not names
  `[routerLink]="['/admin', 'filter']` or `[routerLink]="['Admin/Filter']`

Comment: Ah, right, I was simply trying some thing to make it work.  Having it or not having it did not seem to make a difference...

Comment: `/...` in `path: '/admin/...',` for child routes didn't work for me in rc.x. Try removing it

Comment: There is also no `name` in the new rc.x routers routes

Comment: In the new router the `[routerLink]`s take a list of path segments, not names.

Comment: Followed your advice and removed the names and changed the [routerLink]. so now i have `[routerLink]="['/home']"` but I am getting `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component "AppComponent" has no route named "home".` so now no routing is working correctly...

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Move the `*` route at the end of the list.

Comment: I think it is too big to reproduce in plunker...

I changed home to * and added it to the end, got the same error

`<a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['*']">Home</a>`

Comment: That wasn't what I had in mind, In `@Routes()` make `*` the last route

Comment: `{ path: '/home', component: HomeComponent },` and `<a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>` is giving me that error.  I added `{ path: '*', component: HomeComponent }` to the end of the @Routes